# Javascript class members become null after page finished loading

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how the states of members of classes in Javascript work.

I'm trying to create a dialog class which has the ability to hide the dialog when a user clicks the cancel button.  I've simplified the implementation to show the problem I'm facing.

```
class FooClass {
    bar

    createBar() {
        this.bar = document.createElement("ons-dialog");
        this.bar.innerHTML = "this is bar content";
        document.querySelector("#home").appendChild(this.bar);
        this.bar.addEventListener(
            'click',
            this.hideBar);
        this.bar.show();
    }

    hideBar() {
        if(this.bar) {
            console.log("bar exists: " + this.bar);
            this.bar.hide();
        } else {
            console.log("bar is null!")
        }
    }
}

foo = new FooClass();
foo.createBar();
```

When I click the dialog that comes up when the page completes loading, nothing happens and the output in the console is always:

```
bar is null!
```

Why does the class lose `this.bar` after the page completes loading?  Furthermore, how can I assign an event listener to some button which closes the dialog within this class?

Here is a codepen.io link with implementation:

https://codepen.io/moonlightcheese/pen/NWpxxMj?editors=1111

Comment: `this` inside the `hideBar` function refers to the DOM element (`this.bar`), not the class instance. Try `this.bar.addEventListener('click', this.hideBar.bind(this));` Try `console.log(this)` and see for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript classes, methods are not automatically bound to the instance. E.g. when using a method from a class as an event handler, like you are doing, `this` will point to the element you attach the listener to.

To fix that, you have two options:

1. In the `constructor` of your `class`, bind the method to the instance:

```js
constructor() {
    this.hideBar = this.hideBar.bind(this);
}
```

```js
class FooClass {
  bar;

  constructor() {
    this.hideBar = this.hideBar.bind(this);
  }

  createBar() {
    this.bar = document.createElement("ons-dialog");
    this.bar.innerHTML = "this is bar content";
    document.querySelector("#home").appendChild(this.bar);
    this.bar.addEventListener(
      'click',
      this.hideBar);
    this.bar.hidden = false;
  }

  hideBar() {
    if (this.bar) {
      console.log("bar exists: " + this.bar.outerHTML);
      this.bar.hidden = true;
    } else {
      console.log("bar is null!")
    }
  }
}

foo = new FooClass();
foo.createBar();
```

```html
<div id="home"></div>
```

2. Use a class property and assign an arrow function:

```js
hideBar = () => { /* your function code */ }
```

```js
class FooClass {
  bar;

  createBar() {
    this.bar = document.createElement("ons-dialog");
    this.bar.innerHTML = "this is bar content";
    document.querySelector("#home").appendChild(this.bar);
    this.bar.addEventListener(
      'click',
      this.hideBar);
    this.bar.hidden = false;
  }

  hideBar = () => {
    if (this.bar) {
      console.log("bar exists: " + this.bar.outerHTML);
      this.bar.hidden = true;
    } else {
      console.log("bar is null!")
    }
  }
}

foo = new FooClass();
foo.createBar();
```

```html
<div id="home"></div>
```

Please note that due to the missing custom element definition, the custom element `ons-dialog` does not have a `show` and `hide` method (it's simply an `HTMLUnknownElement` here in the snippet), which is why I replaced that functionality in the snippets using the standard DOM `hidden` API.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer.  i'm not sure why arrow functions differ from member functions in this way.  Javascript is really confusing for me coming from mostly Java coding.

Comment: Arrow functions differ from standard functions in the way that they preserve the `this` reference to whatever `this` was at the point of defining the function, and `bind` is not available on arrow functions.

Comment: Binding the function is the preferred way, though. See https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1 for more details.